# What reason to use indexing of particular rows in a table?

Tags: oracle, indexing

There is [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1161) of using a function-based indexes in the documentation Concepts Oracle 11G:

> A function-based index is also useful for indexing only specific rows
>   in a table. For example, the cust_valid column in the sh.customers
>   table has either I or A as a value. To index only the A rows, you
>   could write a function that returns a null value for any rows other
>   than the A rows.

I can imagine only this use case: the reducing size of index, by eliminating some rows by condition. Is there other use cases when this possibility is useful?

Comment: For example a COMPLETED column that is Y for 99.999% of the rows and you only want to query those with COMPLETED != Y. Then such a small index on NULLIF(COMPLETED,'Y') would make queries on WHERE NULLIF(COMPLETED,'Y') IS NOT NULL or WHERE NULLIF(COMPLETED,'Y') = 'N' able to do a FAST FULL scan of the index very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at function-based indexes:

```
SQL> create table tab1 as select object_name from all_objects;

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TAB1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> select count(*) from tab1 where lower(object_name) = 'all_tables';


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1117438016

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    19 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    19 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1 |   181 |  3439 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(LOWER("OBJECT_NAME")='all_tables')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         63  consistent gets
          ...
```

As you know, all the objects have unique names, but oracle has to analyze all 181 rows and performs 63 consistent gets (physical or logical block reads)

Let's create a function-based index:

```
SQL> create index tab1_obj_name_idx on tab1(lower(object_name));

Index created.

SQL> select count(*) from tab1 where lower(object_name) = 'all_tables';

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 707634933

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                   |     1 |    17 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE   |                   |     1 |    17 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| TAB1_OBJ_NAME_IDX |   181 |  3077 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(LOWER("OBJECT_NAME")='all_tables')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          2  consistent gets
          ...
```

As you can see the cost cuts down (from 18 to 1) dramatically and there are only 2 consistent gets.

So function-based indexes can increase the performance of your application very well.